# Requiring Dojo Classes Like Import ClassFolder.*; in Java

Tags: dojo

I have 100 different dojo classes placed inside a folder. Is there anyway to include them without requiring them one by one.

```
 require([
        "ClassFolder/*",
        "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function(
        myClasses
      ) { ...... });
```

I am using Dojo 1.10.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not thing it is possible directly in dojo 1.10 because you have no possibility to retrieve the list of files from the file system in the browser.

An idea could be to build an utility function in node.js which can output an array of references to your `AMD` modules, the array could be ¨included¨ in your JS application loaded byt he browser.

We are using a similar approach when preparing a special file for the dojo build, where we need to create a module (layer) containing more that 150 references to our dojo classes and widgets.

So basically instead to manually input in `require([],function(){})` manually each file, we have node create the  layer with the right path for requiring our modules.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can't add node to my stack for this task.